# Type of undefined functions in Sympy

Tags: sympy

Suppose I have the following:

```
x=Symbol('x')
f=Function('f')(x)
type(f)
f
```

Why is `type(f)=f`?

Why it is not ***UndefinedFunction***?

How can I identify this kind of functions more generally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer

It's an instance of AppliedUndef, because it's been "applied" (to variable x). Before that, it was an UndefinedFunction.

#### Explanation

Let's consider two steps separately: creating a function and applying it. When they are mixed together, we lose the difference between functions and expressions, which is a common source of confusion in SymPy and in math generally.

#### Unapplied functions

```
>>> f = Function('f')
>>> type(f)
<class 'sympy.core.function.UndefinedFunction'>
```

This is an undefined function. Notably, it's a class and not an object. Perhaps it should be an object ([a long-standing issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/4787)) but on the other hand, this behavior is consistent with defined functions (`sin`, `log`) being classes.  You can test for f being an UndefinedFunction:

```
>>> from sympy.core.function import UndefinedFunction
>>> isinstance(f, UndefinedFunction)
True
```

#### Applied functions

When you apply f to x, creating `f(x)`, the result is a SymPy expression of class `f`, just as `sin(x)` is an expression of class `sin`. How can we test this expression for being an undefined function applied to something? let's see:

```
>>> type(f(x)).__mro__
(f, AppliedUndef, Function, Application, <class 'sympy.core.expr.Expr'>, <class 'sympy.core.basic.Basic'>, <class 'sympy.core.evalf.EvalfMixin'>, <class 'object'>)
```

So, AppliedUndef is the class you want to check here.

```
>>> from sympy.core.function import AppliedUndef
>>> isinstance(f(x), AppliedUndef)
True
```

#### Conclusion

Test with `isinstance(..., ...)`, not with `type(...) == ...`